# SQL combine multiple rows in the same table, into the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, self-join

I have two tables, and table 1 (Customer) only has a limited number of rows, so I want to be able to enter Customer information into this this table (Customer), and save it across two rows, I then want to be able to read these two rows, and combine them into one row and display it as one row using SQL.

I am able to read from the table as normal, I am linking the Customer database with the CustomerDetails Database, as CustomerDetails Contains a unique value needed to display the Columns in Customer

```
SELECT c.Cust_4, c.Cust_5, C.Cust_6  //Selecting the rows to display from Customer
FROM Customer C //From the Customer Database, as C
LEFT JOIN CustomerDetails CD ON C.Unique_val = CD.Unique_val. Joining the Customer DB with CustomerDetails DB, where the 'Unique_val' is the same.

INNER JOIN (SELECT Cust_40, MAX(CREATE_DT) AS MaxTime FROM Customers GROUP BY Cust_40)
grouped ON grouped.Cust_40 = C.Cust_40 //Taking the latest created entry in the Customer Database, Grouped by Cust_40, so it reads the most RECENT version

WHERE grouped.MaxTime = C.CREATE_DT //
AND CD.F_ID = 12332131 //The UNIQUE value inside of the CustomerDetails Database
```

Result:

```
c.Cust_4     c.Cust_5     C.Cust_6
 Info1         Info2        Info3
```

Now this works perfectly, it always reads the LATEST row GROUPING Cust_40, so if there are 10 entries WHERE Cust_40 = 'DavesRow', then it will display 1 row for 'DavesRow' with the latest values.

Now, lets say the Customer Database has a limited number of rows, so I want to have 20 rows, but it only has 10.
Now my goal is to 'SELF JOIN' the Customer Database with itself, and read two or more rows, and combine them as the same row, WHERE certain values are the same

Here is an example of two rows,

```
Cust_4     Cust_5     Cust_6    Cust_40
 Info1      Info2      Info3    DavesRow


Cust_4     Cust_5     Cust_6    Cust_40
Info4       Info5      Info6    DavesRow
```

My attempted SQL to merge these rows, as one row:

```
SELECT c.Cust_4, c.Cust_5, c.Cust_6 d.Cust_4, d.Cust_5, d.Cust_6 //reading the same 3 rows, but from two different entries
    FROM Customer C 
    INNER JOIN Customers D ON D.Cust_39 = C.Cust_39 //SELF JOINING Customers ON Customers where CUST_39 is the same value

    LEFT JOIN CustomerDetails CD ON C.Unique_val = CD.Unique_val  // Joining the Customer DB with CustomerDetails DB, where the 'Unique_val' is the same.
    
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Cust_40, MAX(CREATE_DT) AS MaxTime FROM Customers GROUP BY Cust_40)
    grouped ON grouped.Cust_40 = C.Cust_40 //Taking the latest created entry in the Customer Database, Grouped by Cust_40, so it reads the most RECENT version
    
    WHERE grouped.MaxTime = C.CREATE_DT 
    AND grouped.MaxTime = D.CREATE_DT // THE CREATE_DT WILL BE THE SAME FOR EACH ROW 

    AND CD.F_ID = 12332131 //the CustomerDetails F_ID value will be different, it will be '12332131' for the 'C' instance of Customers, and '13424251' for the 'D' instance of Customers
    AND CD.F_ID = 13424251
```

This doesn't work properly... its displaying the values for c.Cust_4, c.Cust_5, and c.Cust_6 across all 6 rows :c.Cust_4, c.Cust_5, c.Cust_6,  d.Cust_4, d.Cust_5, d.Cust_6

Result

```
c.Cust_4     c.Cust_5     c.Cust_6    d.Cust_4    d.Cust_5    d.Cust_6   
  Info1       Info2       Info3        Info1       Info2       Info3
```

Desired Result

```
c.Cust_4     c.Cust_5     c.Cust_6    d.Cust_4    d.Cust_5    d.Cust_6   
  Info1       Info2       Info3        Info4       Info5       Info6
```

I hope I've explained this okay...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Sample data as well as desired results would help.

Comment: No table has a limited number of rows..